# Lambda function not running other async function even with await added to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, async-await

I have a Lambda function that isn't running an async function that I am using await on. I am guessing something else is async and I need to await it though I am unsure what can/should be await'ed as documentation for the `redis` package doesn't talk about promises or async that I saw. I tried putting `await` in front of the `clienthmset...` but VS Code says I can't await that. What are my options for getting this to run properly?

Here is the minimum reproducable code I have come up with, note the only things not included in this example are my logger, my imports and my client setup (has password and hostname)

```
const loadRedis = async (message) => {
  client.hmset(`${message.region}:${message._id}`, message, (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
      logger.error(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
      reject(err)
    }
    if(res) {
      logger.info(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`)
      resolve(res)
    }
  })
}

module.exports.loader = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  let input = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
  let message = input.Message

  
  const result = await loadRedis(message)
  logger.info(message)
  logger.info(result)
  
  let output = result
  callback(null, output);
};
```

The logs in CloudWatch Logs shows that the message log is coming find but the result one is coming back with nothing at all other than the log level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadRedis` is declared `async`, but you don't return anything, so it's not really await-ing anything..

Probably you just need to do:

```
const loadRedis = async (message) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return client.hmset(`${message.region}:${message._id}`, message, (err, res) => {
      if(err) {
        logger.error(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
        reject(err)
      }
      if(res) {
        logger.info(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`)
        resolve(res)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the `redis` package doesn't support promises so I'm guessing that is out. I thought it would return via the resolve/reject being called, I guess not?

Comment: no but you can just return the promise yourself... see edit

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try, I did something similar before but didn't have the returns

Comment: Finally had time to test it out and this works perfectly, thank you very much for the help.